# HttpClient fails on certain requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dotnet-httpclient

I can make some requests to the web service and they work fine - However this one returns the error message.

- "One or more errors occurred"
- "The underlying connection was closed:An unexpected error occurred on a receive."
- "Unable to read data from    the transport connection: An existing
  connection was forcibly closed    by the remote host."

I've debugged the web service and it returns the correct JSON.

Below is the code I use to call the web service. I have tried Async / Await but it didn't make an difference.

```
 public static string PostURL(string uri, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> pairs)
    {
        try
        {
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var response = httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString();
            else
                return "Failed";
        }
        catch(AggregateException e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }

    }
```

This is the bit of code calling the HttpClient Post

```
   public ActionResult JobDetails()
    {
        var response = WebServicePost.PostURL(WebServicePost.Uri + "JobService.svc/GetJob/", new List<KeyValuePair<String, String>> 
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("JobID", "46"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("CompanyCode", System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CompanyCode"].Value)
            });
        List<Job> list = (List<Job>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.ToString(), typeof(List<Job>));
        return View(list);
    }
```

This then populates the a DataTable on the front end.

The call to the web service is the following.

```
  public List<Job> GetJob(Stream streamData)
    {
        dynamic jObject = streamReader.ConvertToDynamicJsonObject(streamData);
        int jobID = int.Parse(jObject["JobID"]);
        using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
        {
            using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    var query = session.QueryOver<Job>().Where(x => x.JobID == jobID).List();
                    return query.ToList();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Logger.log("Exception at GetJob", e.Message);
                    return null;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Could be related to the size of the request/response. Check your `HttpClient.MaxResponseContentBufferSize`. I believe there may also be a setting in web.config but I can't find any info on that currently. There is also an alternative possible solution here ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720435/httpclient-buffer-size-limit-exceeded

Comment: Post the exception ToString. Also, hook in Fiddler as a proxy and make sure that the app is receiving what you expect.

Comment: What is `HttpClient` in your code? That object definition isn't shown.

Comment: @DavidG HttpClient is just HttpClient object. E.g HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

Comment: @JamesReeves It's confusing because `httpClient` does not equal `HttpClient` (note the capitalisation)

Comment: I guess this makes me slightly nervous that the reason you are getting errors is because there is more code you are not showing here. Have you provided a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: @DavidG Added more code.

Comment: Just to clear something up, you are calling a URL of `GetAllJobs` but the method is called `GetJob`, perhaps that is the issue?

Comment: Sorry that was me testing to make sure my HttpClient post works - and it does. It should be GetJob (I will change that now).

Comment: Can you see the frustration from our side now? When will you finally give us the actual code that is giving you the error? We have no way of knowing if this is the final code or you have some other secret stuff that is the actual problem...

Comment: I don't understand the frustration now. This contains everything. It uses the fluent nhibernate framework, and it has a mysql database. The only thing missing is the nhibernate Job Model / JobMapping class. There is nothing else missing. I don't know what else I can give to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an AggregateExeption that is being thrown, then it is almost definitely being caused within:

```
HttpClient.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;
```

or:

```
response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString();
```

I say this as in my experience AggregateExceptions are generally raised within tasks.

Without knowing what you are trying to post, and the API you are trying to post to, I can't say what the specific error is.
My first check would be that in the request that causes the error there are no typo's or other such mistake.
Then I would check if any of the pairs contain reserved keywords, as this can also be a problem.

Not a solution, but hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ReadAsStringAsync, do you need another .ToString()?  Also wondering if evaluating the .Result twice is closing your connection early.  I'm curious if the solution below would work for you.

```
public async static Task<string> PostURL(string uri, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> pairs)
{
    try
    {
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string resp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return resp;
        }
        else
            return "Failed";
    }
    catch (AggregateException e)
    {
        return e.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: No it didn't work. It got to the var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content); and then carried on with the application - Before a result was even generated.

Comment: That implies something is wrong with the async/await because that shouldn't happen. Did you modify JobDetails() to await Task<string> instead of just string?