# Why does this download the large file, but hang the UI thread?

Tags: c#, events, asynchronous, delegates, async-await

```
static async void DownloadData(TextBox textboxURL, TextBlock outputView)
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(textboxURL.Text);
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, textboxURL.Text);

            /// Fixed thanks to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720435/httpclient-buffer-size-limit-exceeded
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
            /// Version = response.Version.ToString();
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            // Result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            // Task<Stream> inputStream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

            /// DUPE CODE: var sendTask = client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
            /// NEED TO READ UP ON THIS: response..Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var httpStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

            var picker = new FileSavePicker()
            {
                SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Downloads,
                SuggestedFileName = "DOWNLOADING.BIN"
            };

            picker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Any", new List<string>() { "." });
            /// picker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Any", new List<string>() { "*" });

            StorageFile storageFile = await picker.PickSaveFileAsync();

            // Woohoo!  Got it working using await, and removing the Task<> wrapper!
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(httpStream))
            {
                Stream fileStream = await storageFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();

                httpStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                fileStream.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        outputView.Text = "Error, try again!";
        var dlg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(ex.Message, "Error");
        await dlg.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling this method, you might be blocking the Synchronization context, so the block would be genuine. Also `void` return big no, please return a `Task`

Comment: How do I get it to return a Task correctly?

Comment: please elaborate, not sure, what you mean, is it how would map returned Task correctly to a caller. Here `Task` (non generic) is without a return value and is a better replacement of void, especially if there's a exception in the Async method

Answer (score 5):

You're using the synchronous `Stream.CopyTo` method here:

```
httpStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
```

I think you just want:

```
await httpStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
```

However, you should also remove the `StreamReader` part - you're not *using* the `StreamReader`, and it's possible that it will try to read some data to detect the encoding. However, you *should* use a `using` statement for the storage file. So basically, change this:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(httpStream))
{
    Stream fileStream = await storageFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();

    httpStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    fileStream.Flush();
}
```

to:

```
using (Stream fileStream = await storageFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    await httpStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
}
```

Comment: Can someone explain to me why
 await httpStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
has to be "await", and not just a regular line of code?

Comment: @Scott: Well if you don't await it, the calling thread will immediately move on to the next line and close the stream... It sounds like you may benefit from reading up on what async/await does and how it does it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm old school.

Comment: @Scott: The old way of accomplishing this task was to use a `BackgroundWorker`, but await makes it *way* simpler.  Personally, I find Stephen Cleary's [Task.Run vs BackgroundWorker](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html) article to make a good tutorial for those trying to migrate from `BackgroundWorker` to async.  Because it's framed as a comparison between old and new approaches, it's far easier to follow for those who are more accustomed to older approaches.

Comment: Thanks.  I am new to UWP / WinRT Development.  :-)