# System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Cannot write more bytes to the buffer than the configured maximum buffer size: 2147483647

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I am downloading a file from a remote server. The file is more than 2GB in size. I am requesting the file by calling

```
await _client.SendAsync(message, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
```

However, the call is throwing the above exception.

How can I download a file > 2GB?

Comment: If you read the question you would see that I have already applied the answer to the referenced question, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You had this problem on full .NET Framework or Core?

Comment: Hello. Did you solve the problem? How?

Comment: The person having closed this didn't even take the time to understand that Nikki Locke didn't ask for the header but for the whole response content... Typical StackOverflow...

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is very similar with following page.

[HttpClient buffer size limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720435/httpclient-buffer-size-limit-exceeded?rq=1)

Hope this will work for you.