# System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Cannot write more bytes to the buffer than the configured maximum buffer size

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I am downloading a file from a remote server. The file is more than 2GB in size. I am requesting the file by calling

```
await _client.SendAsync(message, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
```

However, the call is throwing the above exception.

How can I download a file > 2GB?

Please note this is **not** a duplicate of [HttpClient buffer size limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720435/httpclient-buffer-size-limit-exceeded)  - I have already applied the answer to that question `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`

Comment: But you already have the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59513142/system-net-http-httprequestexception-cannot-write-more-bytes-to-the-buffer-than)

Comment: `ResponseHeadersRead` allows to read the headers and terminate. How are you actually reading the response Stream and writing it to a file (you won't read it in memory, of course)?

Comment: It doesn't get that far. It throws the exception in SendAsync.

Comment: I repeated the question because it was incorrectly marked as a duplicate and closed.

Comment: You should really post your complete code. It's not even clear why you're using `SendAsync()` instead of `GetAsync()`. Are you waiting for a confirmation response? There's a lack of context here.

Comment: Code is on github at https://github.com/nikkilocke/BaseCampApi/blob/master/BaseCampApi/BasecampApi.cs in function SendMessageAsyncAndGetResponse

Comment: The problem seems to have gone away - I wonder if there was some delay in Nuget or somewhere in updating the code when I added the `ResponseHeadersRead`?